# Regarding broadcast receiver android

Tags: android

Can an activity be invoked using a `BroadcastReceiver`? The `onReceive` for `BroadCast receiver` will be triggered whenever the user presses the power button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we can invoke try below code

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Activity.class);
mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplication().startActivity(mIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start the activity from BroadcastReceiver in the following way

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent intentStart = new Intent(context, StartActivity.class);
    intentStart.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intentStart);
}
```